# How i can create a new string with two reversed last letters of another string?

Tags: javascript, string

I tried use conditional (Ternary) Operator but i dont know how to select just the last and second-last letters of string [enter image description here][1]

Comment: You don't appear to have made any attempt. You can use `word.length` to get the length of your string, and `word.charAt(...)` to get a character at a position. You should be able to figure it out from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without just giving you the answer, if you're ever stuck with a Javascript problem in which you need to manipulate primitives(like string, number, etc.), I'd suggest you look into the methods available. Here is w3schools' list of **string methods**:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

In your case, you might first try the **slice method**:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp

Then, you'll need a way to reverse the string. There's no clear string method for this but there are other approaches such as converting the string into an array, reversing the order of that array, then joining the array elements into a string. See here for solutions like that and others:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-reverse-a-string-in-javascript-in-3-different-ways-75e4763c68cb/

Comment: Thanks! I solved the question with your help. I'm quite a beginner so simple problems are still very difficult for me, but i keep on trying to solve them. 

sorry for my eng im not native english speaker

Comment: Happy to help :). I know how difficult things can feel at first. You might consider joining a forum or chat room meant for Javascript beginners where you can get help better suited to your level. Try the freecodecamp gitter: https://gitter.im/FreeCodeCamp/home. This will work even better for you if you follow the freecodecamp JS curriculum since people there will know it. I'm not affiliated with freecodecamp, I just think they're good for beginners.

Folks on Stackoverflow assume you're able to make at least little progress with a given problem so getting feedback here might be challenging.